# A question about graphs not having non-trivial automorphisms

Tags: graph-theory

Let call a simple graph (not containing neither loops, nor multiple edges) "prime", if it has no non-trivial automorphisms, i.e. graph that has only "identity" automorphic transformation. I cannot find an example of prime graphs. Do they exist?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, they're called asymmetric graphs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_graph According to this wikipedia page, the smallest nontrivial example is on 6 vertices, and there are infinitely many examples. Moreover, almost all graphs are asymmetric in the sense that the ratio of graphs with nontrivial automorphisms tends to zero as the number of vertices grow.

Comment: I thought the term was rigid graph

Comment: Thanks to Yuichiro Fujiwara and Benjamin Steinberg for their help! Wikipedia calls such graphs asymmetric, but Wolfram calls them rigid. I received answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frucht's theorem states that every finite group is the group of automorphisms of a finite undirected graph. The Frucht graph, is a $3$-regular graph whose automorphism group is the trivial group.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht%27s_theorem

Comment: Thanks to Pablo. It looks like almost all small graphs are symmetric.